# How to use Long type path variable with #mvn.url in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I am trying to build a URL to a controller method with the following signature:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/edit/{id}")
public String editPlace(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    Place place = placeRepository.getOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("place", place);
    return "admin/place/addPlace";
}
```

I have ended up with such markup

```
<a th:href="${#mvc.url('PC#editPlace').arg(0,__${place.id}__l).build()}">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
</a>
```

Now, is that a right approach? Please notice that `,__${place.id}__l` (ends with L) is not a typo as I am specifying this way that resolved value is of type `LONG` without that, I got exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source to convert from must be an instance of [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable java.lang.Long]; instead it was a [java.lang.Integer]
```

This approach feels haxy. Is this the how-it-should-be approach or I am using my tools in wrong way?